# Проблема с запуском maven web приложения в idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, tomcat

Я, скорее всего, чего-то не знаю или не понимаю, заискался уже в инете.

**Описание:**

есть 2 `web` приложения, одно из них сделано с помощью `maven`, другое просто java ee web.

При запуске maven приложений через `tomcat` мне выдаётся домашняя страница `tomcatA`, учитывая, что у меня есть одна страница `index.html`. При запуске обычного `java` ee `web` запускается именно `index.html`.

**Вопрос:**

Что это за чудеса настроек, помогите, пожалуйста. `Web.xml` присутствует, `war` файл деплоится на сервер, всё как положено. Причём `maven` приложение вообще создано по инструкции с видео, только вот на видео всё нормально запускается.

Могу кинуть любые скрины, файлы и т.д.

**Структура проекта:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код:**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>I'm first template</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.vebinar</groupId>
    <artifactId>demotest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demotest</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.43</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите структуру проекта и код.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh я добавил структуру и код в описание вопроса. Ещё какие-нибудь дополнения нужны?

Comment: У вас на скрине, видно что идее не нравится pom.xml

Comment: @hersir1 Maven не подхватил зависимости. Подсвечивает же красным.

Comment: @hersir1 В консоли команда mvn --version, что пишет? Кликаем на красную ошибку и Alt+Enter, IDEA предложит исправить ситуацию.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh maven красным больше не подсвечивает, там два раза было указано <properties>, не помогло. mvn --version пишет maven 3.5.3. Подробнее на картинке в описании, добавил

Comment: @hersir1 А с какого ресурса все делаете? Можно ссылку?

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh, конечно. Вот: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DclLJt8zDWk&t=1037s . К слову, там у 4-ёх каких-то ребят такой же косяк, в коментах можно увидеть

Comment: @hersir1 Вот [тут](https://github.com/vladimirGlinskikh/DemoTest) исходник с этого видео. Все работает. Возможно у Вас проблема с 10 версией JDK. Попробуйте 8.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh эх, к сожалению, нет. Очень странная штука, попробую на компьютере друга, может, поможет. Спасибо за ваши старания помочь

Comment: @hersir1 Приложение простое. Летает на Tomcat'e и Jetty. Возможно, что-то не так делаете.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh да я тупо скачиваю исходники и та же штука происходит. Вряд ли запуск происходит неправильно. Может, какие-то настройки из вне

Comment: @hersir1 Попробуй вот этот [тест](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruG0SkRildo). Просто сделай, как в видосе.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh, ты не поверишь! Просто в deployment закладке tomcatA, нужно деплоить не обычный варник, а exploded. Чудеса. Огроменное человеческое спасибо!

Comment: @hersir1 Рад был помочь.